Is there a function whose Fourier transform gives peaks/impulse at multiple desired locations?
Fourier transform of sinusoidal waveforms have 2 peaks depending on the frequency of waveform. We can change their frequency to get a peak at desired location.
Similarly, is/are there functions whose FT gives multiple peaks (>2) at desired locations? I think unless we add multiple sine or cosine waves, we cannot get this but wanted to confirm.
Edit: The FFT of $\cos(ft)$ has peaks at $f$ and $-f$ and is zero everywhere else. Similarly, is there a function x(t,a,b,c,d...) which gives a peak at $a, b, c, d...$ and is zero everywhere else? The only thing I can think of is $\cos(at)+\cos(bt)...$

Another possibility is to use multiple Gaussian prototypes each shifted to whatever desired frequencies you want.  Overlap and add them.  Then take the inverse Fourier transform and you have your function whose fourier transform gives peaks at mutilple desired locations.


Similarly, is/are there functions whose FT gives multiple peaks (>2) at desired locations?

This follows directly from the inverse DFT.
$$x[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{N} n}$$
Let's say you have a signal with 6 peaks at $k_0, k_1 ...k_5$. That simply means that $X[k]= 0$ for the non peak locations and the inverse DFT has only 6 terms.
$$x[n] = X[k_0]e^{j\frac{2\pi k_0}{N} n} + X[k_1]e^{j\frac{2\pi k_1}{N} n} + ... X[k_5]e^{j\frac{2\pi k_5}{N} n} $$
So you end up with the 6 individual complex sinusoids. If the indices and spectrum values are conjugate complex, i.e. you can make pairs like $k_1 = N-k_0, X[k_0] = X[k_1]'$ than you end up with 3 real sines or cosines.

Yes any function that repeats in time will have a Fourier component at it's repetition rate, and if it's not a pure frequency but an arbitrary shape that is repeating, higher harmonics of that repetition rate as well (as demonstrated well by the Fourier Series Expansion which shows how we can decompose any continuous single-valued analytic waveform that is periodic over time period $T$ into the sum of an infinite number of frequencies which can consist of DC, the first harmonic at frequency $1/T$, and any of the integer harmonics of this fundamental).  Some common examples are square waves which consist of all odd order harmonics and potentially DC, triangle waves, etc...anything that is not a pure sinusoid will have more than the the two frequency components the OP mentions.
We can also have a waveform that is the sum of two or more independent frequencies, and this resulting summation will have a Fourier Transform with a peak at each of those frequencies.
Please see this recent DSP Puzzle demonstrating how we can use this property in the Fourier Transform to understand characteristics of the time domain signal:
DSP Puzzle - Advanced Signal Forensics - Spread Spectrum PSD

Hi @DanBochen, can you please see my edit? I am not sure I follow you.

@RajaKrishnappa your edit is already covered by Dan's answer! simply a sum of pure frequency tones, with the tone frequencies given by $a,b,c,\ldots$.

Yes there is a function as I described, there are infinitely many functions. One example is a square wave-- a square wave in time consists of odd harmonics in frequency.  The function you are thinking of ($a_1\cos(\omega t+\phi_1) + a_2\cos(\omega t + \phi_2) +\ldots$ ) is simply the Fourier Series for any arbitrary single valued function
